# Is the term "diamond operator" correct?

Tags: java, jls, diamond-operator

The term *diamond operator* is quite popular: Searching Google for *" diamond operator" java* yields 78.300 results and Stack Overflow has its own *diamond-operator* tag.

*The Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition*, section *3.12 Operators* doesn't list `<>` as an operator though. Section *15.9 Class Instance Creation Expressions* refers to it as the *diamond form*. A *diamond operator* is not mentioned in this document.

Is the term *diamond operator* correct? I don't see why you would call this an operator - it's just an empty type argument list after all? Does it make sense to use this term?

Comment: "*it's just an empty type argument list after all?*" - In terms of syntax, yes it is an "empty list". In terms of semantics, however, it is an *inferred* list.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "correct". If you only consider what's on the spec as correct, then it's not correct.

Comment: Technically it's not an operator, but the meaning of a word or phrase is defined by how it's used and understood. "Diamond operator" is in common use.

Comment: *it's just an empty type argument list after all* - the concept of **empty** type argument list doesn't exist. If it's an argument type list, it cannot be empty. You can't just ignore inserting the type in whoever variable you wish to define. So `<>` is a legitimate  new operator.

Comment: @aran The specification literally says *If the type argument list to the class is empty — the diamond form <> [...]*. Also I don't understand why it would follow from this that this is a legitimate new operator.

Comment: I would argue that "diamond operator", while widely used in that context, is not correct and confusing, since there also is an actual diamond operator in other languages where it is used in place of `!=`

Comment: The `<>` syntax is called the "diamond", for obvious reasons (same reason a baseball field is called a diamond, i.e. the shape). Somebody then decided to call it a "diamond operator" because it looks like the `⋄` [diamond operator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22c4/index.htm) math symbol, and the term was quickly accepted and put into use by the community. It's called the "diamond operator" because of the way it *looks*, not because of it's syntactical meaning in the Java language, where it is *not an operator*.

Comment: I think if you want to use “diamond form” instead of “diamond operator,” everyone will understand what you mean, and you will have the solace of knowing you are speaking/writing with perfect accuracy.  But sometimes we speak informally;  for instance, sometimes I say “variable” when I really mean an instance field.  If the word might cause confusion, I will make a point of saying “instance field.”

Comment: @VGR Saying "variable" when you're talking about an *instance field* is perfectly correct, because the Java Language Specification defines fields as being 2 out of the 8 different [kinds of variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) in the Java language. In contrast, saying "diamond operator" is not valid Java, since it is not an operator, just a "diamond" looking syntactical construct.

Comment: *OCP: Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide* - https://books.google.es/books?id=Lwb9CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT758&ots=1SuX6tCIfB&dq=operators%20java%20oracle%20diamond&pg=PT758#v=onepage&q=operators%20java%20oracle%20diamond&f=false

Comment: the point is, Oracle's official documentation shouldn't be referring to it as Operator (with uppercase first character) if that therm is technically incorrect and just a informal name, as an official documentation of a technical context should always be in the technical side of things...I guess

Comment: @tobias_k and the `>>` operator in java has multiple meanings in other contexts/languages. Even multiple meanings in the same language, as in C++. Wouldn't the `>>` java operator be considered as operator either, because also means redirecting the output `print >> object, "Hello world"` in  a diffeent language?